# Record webcam like a dashcam

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, webcam, recording

I would like to use FFmpeg to record the last 5 hours from the webcam to file like a dashcam.
Creating a new file every 5 hour is acceptable, overwriting the current file is too.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There are a myriad 'security camera' apps that will do this. You don't need to reinvent the wheel.